flutter dependency compatibility issue syncfusion flutter pdf
I have a problem with the syncfusion_flutter_pdf dependencie. When I flutter pub get with the latest version I get the following error:
**Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.4.3.
Because syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer <19.1.54-beta doesn't support null safety and syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=19.1.54-beta <22.1.34 depends on http ^0.13.0, syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer <22.1.34 requires http ^0.13.0.
And because syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer >=22.1.34 depends on device_info_plus ^9.0.2 and myfile depends on device_info_plus ^10.1.0, every version of syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer requires http ^0.13.0.
So, because myfile depends on both http ^1.2.1 and syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer any, version solving failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.**
I tried to change the versions of uuid but it causes me more problems. My pubspec is the following:
dependencies:
  barcode: ^2.2.8
  carousel_images: ^1.1.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  custom_navigation_bar: ^0.8.2
  day_night_time_picker: ^1.3.1
  device_info_plus: ^10.1.0
  dio: ^5.4.3+1
  dots_indicator: ^2.1.2
  draggable_sheet: ^1.0.1+3
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  file_picker: ^8.0.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  flutter_quill: ^9.3.21
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.1
  flutter_slidable: ^3.1.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.5
  geocoding: ^3.0.0
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  http: ^1.2.1
  intl: ^0.19.0
  introduction_screen: ^3.1.9
  lottie: ^3.1.1
  path: ^1.9.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.1.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^26.1.38
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^26.1.38
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: any


please help me for my problem this :(
please help me for my problem this :(

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.
